# connection timed out exception while connecting to a ftp server

Tags: java, ftp

I have seen many post related to this error but din't find any proper solution that can work for me.
So I'm posting it again.

I'm trying to upload a file on ft.drivehq.com using apache commons library. I have tried many solutions like firewall settings etc. None of those solutions is working.

This is the code which takes file name from the form field and calls ftp connect method and upload file method.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    ismultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    if(!ismultipart)
    {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>servlet upload</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>no file upload</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        return;

    }

    DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(1 * 1024 * 1024);
    fileItemFactory.setRepository(new File(TMP_DIR_PATH));

    ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm1 = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm2 = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm3 = null;

    try {
        /*
         * Parse the request
         */
        con = Dbconnector.getConnection();
        List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request); 
        Iterator itr = items.iterator();
        String fileName = "";
        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
        System.out.println("item "+item);
        String fName = item.getName();
        System.out.println("fname " + fName);

       fileName = (String) item.getName();       
        System.out.println("filename " + fileName);    


        int x = fileName.lastIndexOf('\\');
        String fN = fileName.substring(x + 1, fileName.length());
        System.out.println(fN);
        SimpleFTPClient client = null;

        \\table to retrieve drivehq login details
        String sq1 = "select * from adserver"; 

        pstm3 = con.prepareStatement(sq1);
        ResultSet rs1 = pstm3.executeQuery();
        String user = "";
        String cld = "";
        while (rs1.next()) {
            client = new SimpleFTPClient();
            cld = rs1.getString("host_name");
            user = rs1.getString("username");
            client.setHost(rs1.getString("host_name"));
            client.setUser(rs1.getString("username"));
            client.setPassword(rs1.getString("password"));
            client.setRemoteFile("pdp_cloud");
            client.setport(21);

            boolean log = client.connect();
            System.out.println(log);
            if (log) {
               if(client.uploadFile(item.getInputStream())) {

                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + user);
                    String sq2 = "insert into upload (file_name,date,file_data)values(?,?,?)";
                    pstm1 = con.prepareStatement(sq2);
                    pstm1.setString(1, fileName);
                    //pstm1.setString(2, "not set");
                   // pstm1.setString(3, "not set");
                    pstm1.setString(2, dateNow);
                    pstm1.setBinaryStream(3, item.getInputStream(), item.getSize());
                    pstm1.execute();

                } else {
                   System.out.println(">>>>>>else");

                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }

        }
        response.sendRedirect("CreateBlocks.html?msg=File Uploaded..");


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        response.sendRedirect("UploadFile.html?msg=Cloud Not Connected");
        // log("Error encountered while uploading file", ex);
    }



}
```

This is the class having the connection method and upload and download file methods. Not using the actual username and password here.

```
     public class SimpleFTPClient {

    /** The URL connection object */
    private URLConnection m_client;
    /** The FTP host/server to be connected */
    private String host;
    /** The FTP user */
    private String user;
    /** The FTP userâ€™s password */
    private String password;
    /** The remote file that needs to be uploaded or downloaded */
    private String remoteFile;
    /** The previous error message triggered after a method is called */
    private String erMesg;
    /** The previous success message after any method is called */
    private String succMesg;
    /**set port number */
    private int port;

    public SimpleFTPClient() {
    }

    /** Setter method for the FTP host/server */
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    /** Setter method for the FTP user */
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    /** Setter method for the FTP userâ€™s password */
    public void setPassword(String p) {
        this.password = p;
    }

    /** Setter method for the remote file, this must include the sub-directory path relative
    to the userâ€™s home directory, e.g youâ€™e going to download a file that is within a sub directory
    called "sdir", and the file is named "d.txt", so you shall include the path as "sdir/d.txt"
     */
    public void setRemoteFile(String d) {
        this.remoteFile = d;
    }

    /** The method that returns the last message of success of any method call */
    public synchronized String getLastSuccessMessage() {
        if (succMesg == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return succMesg;
    }

    /** The method that returns the last message of error resulted from any exception of any method call */
    public synchronized String getLastErrorMessage() {
        if (erMesg == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return erMesg;
    }

    /**method to set port number for host */
    public void setport(int p)
    {
        this.port = p;
    }

    /** The method that handles file uploading, this method takes the absolute file path
    of a local file to be uploaded to the remote FTP server, and the remote file will then
    be transfered to the FTP server and saved as the relative path name specified in method setRemoteFile
    @param localfilename â€“ the local absolute file name of the file in local hard drive that needs to
    FTP over
     */
   public synchronized boolean uploadFile(InputStream is) {
    //public synchronized boolean uploadFile(String localfilename) {
        try {

         //   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(localfilename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            OutputStream os = m_client.getOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int readCount;

            while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            }
            bos.close();

            this.succMesg = "Uploaded!";

            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter sw0 = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter p0 = new PrintWriter(sw0, true);
            ex.printStackTrace(p0);
            erMesg = sw0.getBuffer().toString();

            return false;
        }
    }

    /** The method to download a file and save it onto the local drive of the client in the specified absolut path
    @param localfilename â€“ the local absolute file name that the file needs to be saved as */
    public synchronized boolean downloadFile(String localfilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = m_client.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>"+localfilename);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(localfilename);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int readCount;

            while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            }
            bos.close();
            is.close(); // close the FTP inputstream
            this.succMesg = "Downloaded!";

            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter sw0 = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter p0 = new PrintWriter(sw0, true);
            ex.printStackTrace(p0);
            erMesg = sw0.getBuffer().toString();

            return false;
        }
    }

    /** The method that connects to the remote FTP server */
    public synchronized boolean connect() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("ftp://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port + "/" + remoteFile);
            m_client = url.openConnection();
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.."+"ftp://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + "/" + remoteFile);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter sw0 = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter p0 = new PrintWriter(sw0, true);
            ex.printStackTrace(p0);
            erMesg = sw0.getBuffer().toString();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

sometimes i get erros on this statement also..

```
 OutputStream os = m_client.getOutputStream();
```

and this is the error log -

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at pdp_cloud.SimpleFTPClient.uploadFile(SimpleFTPClient.java:87)
    at pdp_cloud.UploadFile.processRequest(UploadFile.java:161)
    at pdp_cloud.UploadFile.doPost(UploadFile.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is the URL format correct?
can anyone help me please..

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: now its fine i think..

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of libraries are you using ? Have you tried to use org.apache.commons.net.ftp? Is Ftp or Ftps?

So try this :

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;
public class FTPMain {
 FTPClient ftp = null;

public FTPMain(){

    }

    public Object mainFTP() throws Exception {

        try{

            initFTPUploader("myhost.com", "user", "pass", 8080);
            disconnect();
        }catch(Exception e){
            String msg = "Error";
        }

        return "disconnect";
    }
    public  void initFTPUploader(String host, String user, String pwd,int numPort) throws Exception {
        ftp= new FTPClient(); //use new FTPSClient if is FTPS
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
        int reply;
        ftp.connect(host, numPort);
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.login(user, pwd);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.printWorkingDirectory();
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/myDirectory");
        ftp.printWorkingDirectory();
       //ftp.execPBSZ(0);// use this two only if is a ftps connection  
       //ftp.execPROT("P");// use this two only if is a ftps connection  

    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try to open a shell command line and use "telnet host.com numPort" if there is no error, so maybe the error is the your last code, instead there is an error, make sure that the output port that you want to connect to is open in your system configuration.

Comment: Does it work? Can you please select my answer as "acceptance"? thanks

Comment: yes it worked..